# Android Tabs with ListActivity BackButton

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I have 3 Tabs

Tab1,Tab2,Tab3

```
public Class TabLayout extends TabActivity {
    Tab1,Tab2,Tab3
}
```

Each Tab Contains one ListActivity

that means

Tab1>>>Tab1ListActivity(List with Image and Text)

Tab2>>>Tab2ListActivity(List with Image and Text)

Tab3>>>Tab3ListActivity(List with Image and Text)

and if i click on any listitem from(Tab1ListActivity,Tab2ListActivity etc.......)

I'm forwarding to one More Activity(Tab1ListItemActivity,Tab2ListItemActivity etc......)

But My Actual Requirement is if suppose I'm clicking backbutton from Tab2ListItemActivity ,then I

Should be able to forward to Tab2ListActivity

But,if i write my code like this

```
public class Tab2ListItemActivity extends Activity
{

    //on Back Button Pressed

    Intent intent=new Intent(Tab2ListItemActivity.this,TabLayout.class);

    startActivity(intent);

    Tab2ListItemActivity.this.finish();
}
```

when i execute above code I'm able to forward to my TabLayout(Tab1ListActivity) but not to  Tab2ListActivity?,Beacuse

**Tab2ListItemActivity related to  Tab2ListActivity**

Could any one help?

Comment: Why not leave the default behaviour (do not override onBackPressed)? It will restore to previous Activity.

Comment: why do you want to override OnBackPressed when the default behavior is serving your purpose

Answer (score 1):

1. Why are you trying to override the Back button ? I mean, just let the default behaviour take place and then pressing the back button would take you to the previous activity.
2. If you really want to do it your way, then you would need to set the **`tab id`** before launching the TabLayout activity and inside the **`onCreate()`** of TabLayout you would need to check the **`tab id`** and launch the corresponding ListActivity. The **`tab id is 1 by default`** and that is why it is taking you to the `Tab1ListActivity` always.

Answer (score 1):

Why not leave the default behaviour (do not override onBackPressed)? It will restore to previous Activity.

**Solution 1**:

Do not finish the TabLayout Activity. And Leave the default implementation of back button in Tab2ListItemActivity activity.

**Solution 2** (the hard, the force way):

Add the intent extra on what tab it should open.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Tab2ListItemActivity.this, TabLayout.class);
intent.putExtra(TabLayout.EXTRA_TAB_TO_OPEN, 1);
startActivity(intent);
Tab2ListItemActivity.this.finish();
```

in TabLayout Activity

```
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle state) {
    super.onPostCreate(state);
    handleTab(getIntent());
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    handleTab(intent);
}


private void handleTab(Intent intent) {
    // init tabs
    final int tab = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_TAB_TO_OPEN, -1);
    if (tab != -1) {
        getTabHost().setCurrentTab(tab);
    }
}
```

Comment: Solution 1: the back button should automatically close the Tab2ListItemActivity and you can return to previous activity with tab opened that was last opened I doubt the code is needed indeed. Or if it really is, the code: When you are starting the TabLayout Activity you pass the int which indicates what tab to open to an Intent. The TabLayout then retrieves the tab index you passed from Tab2ListItemActivity and opens it.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting same issue but i solve using this solution.

**TabSample.class**

```
public class TabSample extends TabActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();      

      tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1")
              .setIndicator("OPT")
              .setContent(new Intent(this, TabGroup1Activity.class)));

      tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2")
              .setIndicator("EDIT")
              .setContent(new Intent(this, TabGroup2Activity.class)));

      tabHost.setCurrentTab(1); 
    }
}
```

**TabGroup1Activity.class**

```
public class TabGroup1Activity extends TabGroupActivity{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        startChildActivity("OptionsActivity", new Intent(this,OptionsActivity.class));
    }
}
```

**OptionsActivity.class**

```
public class OptionsActivity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.optionspage);

        Button back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BackButton1);
        Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.NextButton1);

        OnTouchListener backListener = new OnTouchListener() {
                public boolean  onTouch  (View  v, MotionEvent  event) {
                    if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                        finish();
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            };

        OnTouchListener nextListener = new OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                 if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                     Intent edit = new Intent(getParent(), EditActivity.class);
                    TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity)getParent();
                    parentActivity.startChildActivity("EditActivity", edit);
                    return true;
                 }
                 return false;
            }
        };

        back.setOnTouchListener(backListener);
        next.setOnTouchListener(nextListener);
    }
}
```

finally over **TabGroupActivity.class** which save all the stat instance.

```
public class TabGroupActivity extends ActivityGroup {
    private ArrayList<String> mIdList;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);       
        if (mIdList == null) mIdList = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

  @Override
  public void finishFromChild(Activity child) {
      LocalActivityManager manager = getLocalActivityManager();
      int index = mIdList.size()-1;

      if (index < 1) {
          finish();
          return;
      }

      manager.destroyActivity(mIdList.get(index), true);
      mIdList.remove(index); index--;
      String lastId = mIdList.get(index);
      Intent lastIntent = manager.getActivity(lastId).getIntent();
      Window newWindow = manager.startActivity(lastId, lastIntent);
      setContentView(newWindow.getDecorView());
  }

  public void startChildActivity(String Id, Intent intent) {     
      Window window = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(Id,intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
      if (window != null) {
          mIdList.add(Id);
          setContentView(window.getDecorView()); 
      }    
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
      if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
          //preventing default implementation previous to android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR
          return true;
      }
      return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
      if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
          onBackPressed();
          return true;
      }
      return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
  }

  public void  onBackPressed() {
      int length = mIdList.size();
      if ( length > 1) {
          Activity current = getLocalActivityManager().getActivity(mIdList.get(length-1));
          current.finish();
      }  
  }
}
```

This is awesome solution you can try this.and make appropriate `manifest` entry.